# Is every connected regular space having more than one point uncountable?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is every connected regular space having more than one point uncountable?

Answer (score 5):

Google is your friend :  "connected regular space" returns

http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Connected_regular_space

The answer is yes, the proof is by contradiction, using that Lindelöf and regular implies normal (even paracompact) .